# Generating a City Layout

Tags: algorithm, layout, geometry

I'm working on a project where I need to generate a city. The problem is, the city must be varied and interesting, so I would like the road layout to somewhat resemble real life roads.

The algorithm:
The city is split into chunks which are loaded when the game is run. Each chunk is square and will have zero, one, or two intersections. Each chunk must line up with the chunks next to it. Assume all of the streets are two way.

What are the possible combinations or road I can place on a chunk that will line up with the chunks around it?

Final product should lean toward the 'fused grid' style of road network:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FusedGridDistrict.png

Comment: what you call "chunks" are rectangular cells?

Comment: are all streets two-way?

Comment: Edited to answer your questions.

Comment: this is too broad subject. Do you have a specific problem ? Which approach are you using to generate? I suspect  you got predefined tiles for each type of "block" so randomly choose from all usable tiles (based on edge compatibility (number and position of roads, water) with already placed neighbor blocks. Similar to Carcassonne game tile placing.

Comment: The map is loaded in a spiral starting with tile (0,0). At this stage of development tiles are provided with their x and y coordinate as well as neighbouring loaded tiles when they are loaded. Each tile will need to check its neighbouring loaded tiles for the points on each edge that a road connects to, but beyond that each tile needs to have some way to make a road that looks 'organic' this is my specific problem.